Can I analyze social media posts from news outlets for research without violating copyright?
I am planning a research project to analyze how different national news outlets cover the same topic. To do this, I wanted to gather articles from various outlets, translate the text into English, and store it in a database for later analysis (such as word frequency and sentiment analysis).
However, since all outlets' websites are copyrighted (all rights reserved), as I understand I cannot copy and store these articles (or their translations), even in a private database.
My question is: Could I instead collect and analyze the posts that these news outlets share on social media (specifically Twitter and Facebook)?  Would this method still violate copyright, or are there differences in how social media posts are treated under copyright law, since they do not contain the entire articles?
